# Where can I find config_ip_nf_nat_local in ubuntu ?

Tags: ubuntu

Can anyone please tell me where i can find the config_ip_nf_nat_local and other netfilter counters in ubuntu?

I am using version Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS.

Regards,
-Suresh

Answer (score 1):

The obvious question is why do you need this deprecated kernel option?

The option `CONFIG_IP_NF_NAT_LOCAL` enables support for NAT of locally originated connections and it was available for Linux kernels `2.6.0–2.6.10`. It was removed as it violates TCP/IP standards.

In [RFC 5735](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5735) is defined that network 127.0.0.0/8 can't  be routed outside of the host:

```
127.0.0.0/8 - This block is assigned for use as the Internet host loopback 
address. A datagram sent by a higher-level protocol to an address anywhere 
within this block loops back inside the host. This is ordinarily implemented 
using only 127.0.0.1/32 for loopback. As described in [RFC1122], Section 
3.2.1.3, addresses within the entire 127.0.0.0/8 block do not legitimately 
appear on any network anywhere.
```

Comment: Hi Dsumsky, I am trying to use netsed to modify the TCP packets in-fly. I have configured a host(PC1) as gateway to another ubnutu PC (PC2). I have configured static IPs for eth1 of PC1 and eth0 of PC2. Both the PCs are connected via cross over cable. I have set the iptables rules to redirect traffic at port 80 to 10101 and used netsed to modify, but netsed is NOT doing what I am expecting. Please suggest what else need to be configured at kernel level ?